Custom Field Type that stores multiple field value as json gets manipulated on form load
I try to create a Custom Form Field that solves the problem where you have to much (visible) fields in a section. For example: a cards module where you have sections for the csard header, body, footer, media. Each of these sections will have a select for the source (com_content) but all of these also comes with additional fields like custom css classes, attributes, aswell as other settings. All these "Additional" setting options will be placed inside a modal - all works so far. On modal close the field values from the modal got taken by js and merged into one json string using this code:
function prepareModalInteractions(modal, targetfield){
    console.log("Modal Interactions launched")
    const closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.nxd-modal-close-btn')
    // Add Event Listener to get the contents of the modal:
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const fields = modal.querySelectorAll('input');
        const fieldValue = compileFieldValue(fields);
        targetfield.value = fieldValue;
    })
}

function compileFieldValue(fields){
    const fieldValues = {};
    for(const f of fields){
        const key = f.name;
        fieldValues[key] = f.value;
    }

    return JSON.stringify(fieldValues)

}

The value is visible in the module settings, after save the value got stored in the database:
Field Value on JS Paste: {"classes":"my-class another-class","attributes":"data-foo=\"bar\""}
Value in DB: ..."title_source":"{\"classes\":\"my-class another-class\",\"attributes\":\"data-foo=\\\"bar\\\"\"}"...
field value on var_export:
'{"classes":"my-class another-class","attributes":"data-foo=\\"bar\\""}'
but the field value in the input field:
{
It looks like it "cleans" out the field value after the first " somehow. My Field is extended of the "FormField" - i do nothing about the value in my code except the js placement on modal save inside the UI.
I've tried already to set "filter=raw" in the xml aswell as set protected $filter="raw" in the Field's php class without success...
When pasting in the generated JSON String manually into the module title for example it stays there...
When using single quotes it will also stay in my field's input (but thats not valid json).
So what do i miss / messed up here?
Edit:
Ok i think i'm near the answer - the problem is that the module parameters (all fields) got stored in the "params" object which will be encoded by Joomla to save the module parameters. Decoding then fails here...
Edit 2:
I'don't know exactly what it is but simply by changing the field html from input to textarea solved my issue...
$fieldValueInput = '<textarea id="' . $this->id . '" class="form-control" name="' . $this->name . '" filter="raw">' . $this->value . '</textarea>';

        $html = '<div id="' . $this->id . '_content_group" class="nxd-content-group">';
        $html .= $fieldToRender;
        $html .= $fieldValueInput;
        $html .= '</div>';

Any hints what happened here would be great...

As mentioned in my question's edit 2 - the solution was to change the field type to textarea rather then text. That way Joomla! did not manipulated the string.
